# Black substances covering Aluminum Electrode

Tags: metal, electrolysis, oxidation-state

I have use two aluminum pieces as electrodes to electrolys salt (NaCl) water. After the experiment, I found that wherever electricity flows, the electrode will be covered in some blackish substances. One electrode has more dark substances than the other

[image]

Are they Al2O3? Or are they some other substances? Why is one electrode having more and the other having less?

Comment: Alloying in the aluminum, maybe?